# How can I extend a circuit from an outlet in a wall to the surface of concrete with conduit?

Tags: electrical, receptacle, conduit

I currently have an outlet as can be seen in the image below. What I would like to do is to add some outlets to the brick wall that you can also see in the image. I was thinking about using some metal conduit and using metal boxes to run the outlets. Where I am having trouble is figuring out the least destructive way to add the outlets. I don't have to have the existing outlet, so I could use this as some sort of a junction box. Any ideas on how to do this?

[image: Wall outlet and wall]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can remove the cover plate and outlet and install a box entender similar the the one below.

[image]

Then run your conduit out of this box to the additional flush mounted boxes and outlets. If these outlets will be in a basement or garage they will need to be GFCI protected.

Answer (score 4):

Put an extension box (or box extender) on the outlet box, and run conduit from that along the wall, assuming you are OK with the aesthetics of that.

For a slightly "nicer" look, use wiremold instead of conduit.  I don't mind conduit, myself, and it costs a lot less.

Comment: I UV'd because of the wire mold... but I have always liked conduit when done right.